# Maven error from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I am running Jenkins 1.599. I have created a new freeStyle project, which executes the batch command `mvn clean install`.
If I do run the same batch command from the windows shell, the maven command runs successfully.

However, when Jenkins executes it, I get a maven failure, as shown below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\AppHistData Freestyle\workspace>[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3523791316528515292.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\AppHistData Freestyle\workspace>C:\\develop\\AppHistData\\AppHistDataMvn\\maven_run.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\AppHistData Freestyle\workspace>cd C:\develop\AppHistData\AppHistDataMvn 

C:\develop\AppHistData\AppHistDataMvn>C:\maven-3.2.5\bin\mvn clean install 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AppHistDataMvn 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for TradingInstrument:TradingInstrument:jar:1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for allinonetrade:allinonetrade:jar:1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.823 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-04T12:21:16+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project AppHistDataMvn: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.deepfieldcapital:AppHistDataMvn:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: TradingInstrument:TradingInstrument:jar:1, allinonetrade:allinonetrade:jar:1: Failure to find TradingInstrument:TradingInstrument:jar:1 in http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.netbeans.maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

The POM.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>deepFieldCapital</groupId>
    <artifactId>TradeInstManager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>TradeInstManager</name>
    <organization>
        <name>Deep Field Capital</name>
    </organization>
    <build> 
        <plugins> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.deepfieldcapital.tradeinstmanager.TradeInstrumentManagerMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins> 
    </build>  
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>lib</id>
            <url>file:../lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>TradingInstrument</groupId>
            <artifactId>TradingInstrument</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>BrokerOld</groupId>
            <artifactId>BrokerOld</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Utilities</groupId>
            <artifactId>Utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>allinonetrade</groupId>
            <artifactId>allinonetrade</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Based on your question i will too firstly start to read about the exact configuration/ details. But maven has local as well as remote repositories whereas it seems certain dependencies are available in your local repository (successful build on your machine from windows shell) but not on the remote repository where your current configuration tries to find them. I do know that by `mvn install` you build the artefact and _install_ it in the local repository while `mvn deploy` attempts to _deploy_ it to a remote repository. (both install/deploy are part of the default lifecycle)

Comment: I however dont know if you can just deploy to http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ (where your Jenkins job is looking for the artefacts) or if you need to setup your own remote repository to deploy to (and configure your Maven project to use as first source to look for artefacts right after the local repository to enable Jenkins to pick up the artefacts). Sorry if i got you totally wrong.

Comment: This might help to further specify your setup -> http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html (i am reading this for the first time too so i probably wont be of use from now on)